# Timestamp formatting to shorten the month

Tags: php, timestamp

I am using `<?php echo date("F jS, Y",strtotime($timestamp));  ?>` to format my timestamp to something like `September 26th, 2013`

But how can i make it so it formats and shortens the month to something like `Jan 6th, 2013`
or `Sep 26th, 2013`

Comment: Can you not read this http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use "M" to represent for short name of month.(3 character)

```
<?php echo date("M jS, Y",strtotime($timestamp)); ?>
```

[image]use

[image]

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php